# Unable to copy a .png file to a folder using java (.png/screenshot file generated by selenium) on Win7 machine

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a screenshot generated through selenium for a failed test and I am trying to save it to a folder. But I am getting a java error saying

> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
>     at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
>     at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java:414)
>     at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:589)
>     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1009)
>     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:968)
>     .................

I am using the following code

```
    public void saveScreenShot(TestResult result) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    String actualId = result.getActualId();
    actualId = actualId.replace("/", "-");

    String fileName = String.format(ConfigurationManager.getScreenshotDirectory() + "\\%d&%s.jpg", result.getTestId(), actualId);

    try
    {
        FileUtils.copyFile(getScreenShot(), new File(fileName));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Debug it, put a breakpoint in there. What's the runtime value of `fileName`?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I tried debugging it and it game me a fatal error? I will revisit the problem when I have some time and get back to you with a better explanation. Thanks